# Can we create different tab bars for different views?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

I have two views.

I want to place two different tab bars in each view.

Is that possible? If yes, how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

You just need to create two different `UITabBarControllers` and then add their views to your main view when you need either of them.